# Spring-boot TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

My service method is annotated with Transnational (org.springframework.transaction.annotation)
But still a "TransactionRequiredException" occurs when making an update on table Persons.
A select on the same table works fine.

```
@Transactional
public String myMethod(String contractNo){
    myRepository.resetValues(contractNo);
}

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Persons, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE PERSONS SET status = 0 WHERE LOGIN_NAME like :contractNo", nativeQuery = true)
    void resetValues(@Param("contractNo") String contractNo);
}



@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.mypackage.repositories" }
)
public class EBankingDBConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.eba-datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                        .packages("com.mypackage.model")
                        .persistenceUnit("myPersistenceUnit")
                        .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've identified the problem. There are other db Config classes in the Project because the application accesses multiple databases.   According to Spring, one of the db config files should be considered "primary". This is done by annotating all beans in the config class with Primary.  I found out that the Sping-data Repository  which is associated with db config class which has the  Primary annotation, does do Transactions properly. The other db Config classes (without Primary annotation inside) do not instantiate the transaction manager correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are multiple TransactionManagers beans defined in the project, you have to annotate transactions of non-primary TransactionaManagers with their names. For example, in my config above, the TransactionManager name is defined as "transactionManager".
So, the Transactional annotation on methods should look line this :  @Transactional("transactionManager")